# Compare two arrays with different dimension

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, .net-2.0

I am trying to compare two arrays that always have different dimensions.

```
eg. arr1 -> {1,2,3} and arr2->{1,2}
```

I did try and able to get the matching items to new array. But I am expecting to get the unmatched items only

I am expecting to compare both arrays and put only the item '3' to a new array which is in arr1 and not in arr2

eg arr1 -> {1,2,3} and arr2->{1,2} should result a new array with 3
arr1 -> {1,2,3,4} and arr2->{1,2} should result a array with 3,4

Is there any way of doing this for older version of `.net framework` without using [Enumerable.Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except)

Comment: Which version of .Net are using exactly?

Comment: See what I just did there with your tags?

Comment: Also: what do you want to do about potential duplicate items in arr1? Should the result only include distinct items? Or can you guarantee there will be no duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something like this.
if we have two arrays called `paramOld`{"1","2","3"} and `paramNew`{"2","3"}

```
If paramOld.Length > paramNew.Length Then
            Dim paramDelete((paramOld.Length - paramNew.Length) - 1) As String


            Dim isFound As Boolean = False
            For i As Int32 = 0 To oldparamLenght - 1
                isFound = False
                For j As Int32 = 0 To newparamLength - 1
                    If paramOld(i) = paramNew(j) Then
                        isFound = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                If isFound = False Then
                    paramDelete(i) = paramOld(i)
                End If
            Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use LINQ? `Except()` may be right for you.

```
var arr3 = arr1.Except(arr2);
```

**Edited**

If you can't use LINQ here a quick and dirty version of that function:

```
Public Shared Function Except(a As List(Of Integer), b As List(Of Integer)) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim result As New List(Of Integer)()

    For Each value As Integer In a
        If Not b.Contains(value) Then
            result.Add(value)
        End If
    Next

    For Each value As Integer In b
        If Not a.Contains(value) Then
            result.Add(value)
        End If
    Next

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: is this possible in vb? this way is perfectly fine in c#

Comment: It depends on the .NET version not the language (but yes, you're right example was in C#).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the way is much similar as i found it here **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx**

Comment: Yes, of course! I guess it's a common example for Except()! :)

Comment: do you know a way to do this for older version of .net framework?

Comment: To mimic the ExceptIterator implementation you may use a set (or a simple list where you check for duplicates). Cycle through each collection and add items to the set (if a using a list add the item only if it doesn't exist).

Comment: problem here is this is a older version. Therefore can't import **Data.Linq**, so I can't use the **.Contains** or **.Except**

Comment: Edited with an example **without** LINQ, plain old C#!

Comment: its the same answer you posted one hour ago? may be you didn't saved

Comment: Don't you see the **edited** section? It contains a simple function named Except(), it's a replacement for older versions.

Comment: This isn't Except(). a except b would not need to look for items in b that are not in a. This is closer to a union all b.

Comment: No...every element of A that isn't in B is included in the result. Same for B's elements. To "union" them you should simply check if it's in the result or not (code would be updated to check for duplicates too).

Answer (score 0):

For two sorted arrays of integers with no duplicates, as shown in your examples,

```
Public Function differences(a() As Integer, b() As Integer) As Integer()

    Dim aLen As Integer = a.Length
    If aLen = 0 Then
        Return b
    End If

    Dim bLen As Integer = b.Length
    If bLen = 0 Then
        Return a
    End If

    Dim diff As New List(Of Integer)

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim j As Integer = 0

    Do
        If a(i) = b(j) Then
            i += 1
            j += 1
        ElseIf a(i) > b(j) Then
            diff.Add(b(j))
            j += 1
        ElseIf a(i) < b(j) Then
            diff.Add(a(i))
            i += 1
        End If
    Loop While i < aLen AndAlso j < bLen

    If i < aLen Then
        For k = i To aLen - 1
            diff.Add(a(k))
        Next
    End If

    If j < bLen Then
        For k = j To bLen - 1
            diff.Add(b(k))
        Next
    End If

    Return diff.ToArray

End Function
```