# C# byte array comparison

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have two byte arrays in C# using .NET 3.0.

What is the "most efficient" way to compare whether the two byte arrays contains the same content for each element?

For example, byte array `{0x1, 0x2}` is the same as `{0x1, 0x2}`. But byte array `{0x1, 0x2}` and byte array `{0x2, 0x1}` are not the same.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Well, you could use:

```
public static bool ByteArraysEqual(byte[] b1, byte[] b2)
{
    if (b1 == b2) return true;
    if (b1 == null || b2 == null) return false;
    if (b1.Length != b2.Length) return false;
    for (int i=0; i < b1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (b1[i] != b2[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

(I normally use braces for everything, but I thought I'd experiment with this layout style just for a change...)

This has a few optimisations which `SequenceEqual` can't (or doesn't) perform - such as the up-front length check. Direct array access will also be a bit more efficient than using the enumerator.

Admittedly it's unlikely to make a significant difference in most cases...

You could *possibly* make it faster in unmanaged code by making it compare 32 or 64 bits at a time instead of 8 - but I wouldn't like to code that on the fly.

Comment: For large arrays, say 10k, would parallelizing be an efficient optimization or would the threading overhead be to too much?

Comment: What's your take on `IStructuralEquatable` for this purpose?

Comment: @Lijo: I confess I've never fully understood `IStructuralEquatable` and when it's appropriate.

Answer (score 29):

You can use the [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) method:

```
bool areEqual = firstArray.SequenceEqual(secondArray);
```

As mentioned in the comments, `SequenceEqual` requires .NET 3.5 (or [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) if you're using VS2008 and targeting an earlier version of the framework).

Comment: The most efficient way I think.

Comment: Not in terms of execution time it's not.

Comment: @Veton: It's certainly the least typing! See Jon's answer for a few additional optimisations.

Comment: (Try comparing a byte array containing 1,000,000 entries with one containing 1,000,001 entries via SequenceEqual. It will go right to the end before noticing they have different lengths...)

Comment: This also doesn't work (without something like LINQBridge) in .NET 3.0 as required in the question... although it's possible that the OP meant .NET 3.5.

Comment: I am using .Net 3.0, seems this method only works in .Net 3.5. :-(

Comment: I know this is an old question, but this helped me in 2022!

Answer (score 5):

Jon mentioned comparing multiple bytes at once using unsafe code, so I had to give it a go:

```
public unsafe bool ByteArraysEqual(byte[] b1, byte[] b2) {
   if (b1 == b2) return true;
   if (b1 == null || b2 == null) return false;
   if (b1.Length != b2.Length) return false;
   int len = b1.Length;
   fixed (byte* p1 = b1, p2 = b2) {
      int* i1 = (int*)p1;
      int* i2 = (int*)p2;
      while (len >= 4) {
         if (*i1 != *i2) return false;
         i1++;
         i2++;
         len -= 4;
      }
      byte* c1 = (byte*)i1;
      byte* c2 = (byte*)i2;
      while (len > 0) {
         if (*c1 != *c2) return false;
         c1++;
         c2++;
         len--;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

The safe code gets pretty optimised (the compiler knows that it doesn't have to check index boundaries for example), so I wouldn't expect the unsafe code to be very much faster. Any significant difference would come from the ability to compare several bytes at once.

Comment: Good concept, although the code doesn't compile: "Cannot assign to 'p1' because it is a 'fixed variable'"

Comment: @Edward Brey: You are correct, that won't work. You need to declare new pointers inside the block to have them changeable. I have corrected the code.

Comment: It's faster to use longs (8 bytes) in the comp, even on 32bit machines.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not too concerned about performance, you can consider `IStructuralEquatable`.

.NET Framework Supported in: 4.5, 4

> Structural equality means that two objects are equal because they have equal values. It differs from reference equality.

Example:

```
static bool ByteArrayCompare(byte[] a1, byte[] a2) 
{
  IStructuralEquatable eqa1 = a1;
  return eqa1.Equals(a2, StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer);
}
```

**REFERENCE**

1. [What problem does IStructuralEquatable and IStructuralComparable solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609823/what-problem-does-istructuralequatable-and-istructuralcomparable-solve)
2. [Why aren't IStructuralEquatable and IStructuralComparable generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968580/why-arent-istructuralequatable-and-istructuralcomparable-generic)
3. [IStructuralEquatable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.istructuralequatable.aspx)

Comment: Giving this post a point: this might be a way to do things when we are using the recent versions of the framework.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be really fast, you can use unsafe code (which isn't always possible):

```
    public static bool ArraysEqual(byte[] b1, byte[] b2)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            if (b1.Length != b2.Length)
                return false;

            int n = b1.Length;

            fixed (byte *p1 = b1, p2 = b2)
            {
                byte *ptr1 = p1;
                byte *ptr2 = p2;

                while (n-- > 0)
                {
                    if (*ptr1++ != *ptr2++)
                        return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Update for `.NET 6`.

These days [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal) method is still **the best option**:

```
var byteArray1 = new[]{0x01, 0x02};
var byteArray2 = new[]{0x01, 0x02};

bool isEqual = byteArray1.SequenceEqual(byteArray2);
```

Though, **another option** is also available out-of-the-box – [ReadOnlySpan<T>.SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.sequenceequal), e.g.:

```
bool isEqual = new Span<byte>(byteArray1).SequenceEqual(new Span<byte>(byteArray2));
```

The `Span` approach used to be faster in the pre-.NET 6 time, but the MS folks drastically optimised implementation of `Enumerable.SequenceEqual` that's now using `ReadOnlySpan<T>` under the hood ([PR 1](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/48287), [PR 2](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/48677)). See [Performance improvements in .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-6/) for more info.