# Why aren't IStructuralEquatable and IStructuralComparable generic?

Tags: .net, generics, .net-4.0, equality

`System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable` and `System.Collections.IStructuralComparable` were added in .NET 4, but why aren't they generic, like `IEquatable<T>` and `IComparable<T>`?

Comment: Because C# generics don't let you specify structural requirements for a type parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.istructuralequatable.aspx) gives part of the answer here; it seems to be useful for heterogeneous equality, rather than homogeneous equality - i.e. for testing whether two objects (/values) of *potentially different types* should be considered equal. In such scenarios, it is extremely likely that the calling code is dealing with `object` (to represent heterogeneous data). And generic methods don't play nicely then.

Comment: However, all the `Tuple` classes simply return `false` if the other object isn't exactly the same type. `Array` seems to implement it correctly...

Comment: Array behaves the same as tuple for me. This test fails:             Assert.IsTrue(StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(new[] { 5, 10 }, new[] { 5.0, 10.0 }));

Comment: There is no need for an equality operator that accepts different types. That should not even compile. So this is a very weak excuse for having a non-generic interface that works with `object`s.

Answer (score 0):

I created a generic class which works fine:

```
var d = new Dictionary<int[], int>(new StructuralComparer<int[]>());

var arr1 = new int[] { 2, 3 };
var arr2 = new int[] { 2, 3 };

d.Add(arr1, 7);
Console.WriteLine(d[arr1]);
Console.WriteLine(d[arr2]); // would throw exception with structural comparison

class StructuralComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T? x, T? y) => StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(x, y);
    public int GetHashCode(T obj) => StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(obj);
}
```