# Compare two char[] arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, comparison, char

I have the following C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] st = "stackoverflow".ToCharArray();
            char[] ca = { 's', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k' };
            if (st.Take(5) == ca)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failure");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's intended to write "Success" to the console but it always prints "Failure". Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Posting code and saying "what's wrong" is not a great way to start. What have you tried? Are CharArrays considered equal if their contents are equal? Are they compared by pointer value? This seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389570/c-sharp-byte-array-comparison-issue?lq=1

Comment: Sorry I just googled for like half hour and didn't found a way to accomplish what I wanted, also I tried every code sample I found but I was unable to make it work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`==` only compares the references of the two arrays, not their items, and since the two arrays have two different references, your comparison will always return `false`.

You have to compare the elements of one array to the elements of the other.  You can use [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) to accomplish this.

```
if (st.Take(5).SequenceEqual(ca))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
}
```