# Fastest way to compare two images

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, optimization

I need to compare two images as fast as possible.  I don't need to know the differences or anything else I just need to know if they are the same, yes/no, awesome.  What is the fastest way to do this?

Thanks, R.

Comment: What kind of images? What do you mean by if they "are the same"? If they are identical byte by byte? Or they "look the same" to a human (assuming you mean an image like .png or .jpg)?

Comment: Are they the same format and size? Are they different formats with different compression schemes? Lossy or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way I can compare two equal-size bitmaps to determine whether they are identical?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031217/what-is-the-fastest-way-i-can-compare-two-equal-size-bitmaps-to-determine-whethe)

Answer (score 1):

If they are expected to be the same, byte-by-bye like @NullUserException mentioned, the easiest solution is to use a hash like Md5. If you'd like to get more advanced, you can get the RGB values of each pixel in the first image and calculate the euclidean distance from the pixels in the second image checking to see if it's below some threshold. Everything is else is not fast :)

Comment: wouldn't comparing each file byte by byte until a difference is found be much faster than computing an md5 checksum for both?

Comment: @JoshD: it would certainly be much much faster for images that differ and merely much faster for images that are the same.

Comment: If you're only comparing one file to another, there's no advantage to using a hash.  However, if you will be comparing one image to many, the time spent computing the hash is amortized over the multiple comparisons of hash values.  Comparing hashes is many times faster than comparing byte for byte because hashes are very small relative to the original data.  If you are trying to determine if a new image is already in a large collection of images, compute the hash once and compare many times (store the hash of each image as it is inserted into the collection so it's cheap and easy to get it).

Answer (score 0):

tldr;

1. image hashing ( phash, dhash, colorhash, average_hash etc)
2. Feature detection using computer vision (opencv)
3. bitwise operations against pixel arrays(opencv)

**UPDATE 2023:** Since this is the top search on google currently I figured I would answer this. There are many ways to do this depending on the image type. Hashing is very quick to do image comparisons. However, each hashing technique differs.

You can look at the [imagehash library (python)](https://pypi.org/project/ImageHash) to get an example of the various hashes you can leverage and see similarities it finds based on the type of hashes such as phash, dhash, colorhash, average_hash etc.

However, sometimes you want to compare features in an image and you should leverage something like opencv to get contours or features to compare images against each other.