# Fast way of calculating differences between two bitmaps

Tags: c#, bitmap, differentiation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the fastest way I can compare two equal-size bitmaps to determine whether they are identical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031217/what-is-the-fastest-way-i-can-compare-two-equal-size-bitmaps-to-determine-whethe)

I'm trying to efficiently calculate the differences between two bitmaps and set any matching pixels black. I've tried this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 1280; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 720; y++)
    {
        if (bitmap.GetPixel(x, y) == bitmap2.GetPixel(x, y))
        {
            bitmap2.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
        }
    }
}
```

But it turns out that GetPixel and SetPixel are slow so this doesn't really work well enough. Anyone know an alternative (faster) way of doing this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry, my bad. At least I know now. Pretty sure I've done it in the past as well so oops!

Comment: @JoeyMorani: thanks for letting me know. I think I've got them all now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method uses unsafe code, assuming bitmaps are the same size and are 4 bytes per pixel.

```
Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0,0,bitmapA.Width,bitmapA.Height);
var bmpDataA = bitmapA.LockBits(bounds, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmapA.PixelFormat);
var bmpDataB = bitmapB.LockBits(bounds, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmapB.PixelFormat);

const int height = 720;
int npixels = height * bmpDataA.Stride/4;
unsafe {
    int * pPixelsA = (int*)bmpDataA.Scan0.ToPointer();
    int * pPixelsB = (int*)bmpDataB.Scan0.ToPointer();

    for ( int i = 0; i < npixels; ++i ) {
        if (pPixelsA[i] != pPixelsB[i]) {
             pPixelsB[i] = Color.Black.ToArgb();
        }
    }
}
bitmapA.UnlockBits(bmpDataA);
bitmapB.UnlockBits(bmpDataB);
```

For a safe method, copy the pixel data to an array buffer for processing using the `InteropServices.Marshal.Copy` methods.

Answer (score 2):

Raw bitmap data and LockBitmap.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp

Question (missing examples).
[What is the fastest way I can compare two equal-size bitmaps to determine whether they are identical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031217/what-is-the-fastest-way-i-can-compare-two-equal-size-bitmaps-to-determine-whethe)

Forget if you turn debug mode off the speed increase. abaut 10x but lockbit is still faster.

Answer (score 1):

Almost sure this has been answered before. You should be using:

[Bitmap.LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx)

Also accessing Width and Height (or the other properties with the same info) is also slow so copy them to a local variable if you want to use them in a loop (instead of say the 720 and 1280 in your example.)