# Compare two arrays and return their remainder

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I am doing an image comparer for learning purposes.

I have done almost everything already and I am now improving it. To check for similarity, I have 2 jagged-multidimensional arrays (`byte[][,]`) where I access each element of each array using a triple for loop and store their remainder, like this:

```
for (int dimension = 0; dimension < 8; dimension++)
{
    Parallel.For(0, 16, mycolumn =>
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 16, myrow =>
        {
            Diffs[dimension][mycolumn, myrow] =
                (byte)Math.Abs(Image1Bytes[dimension][mycolumn, myrow]
                - Image2Bytes[dimension][mycolumn, myrow]);
        });
    });
}
```

Now, I would like to check how much each dimension is equal to another in the other collection.

How could I compare the entire arrays in each array (like `array1[i][,] == array2[j][,]`)?

I think there are better ways to do these operations, but I have managed to do them pretty quickly.

Comment: How do you define "equality" for 2-D arrays?  To the arrays just need the same contents in any order or should they be equal cell-by-cell?

Comment: Cell by cell, like in the triple-for example I gave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an older thread on comparing two images that would be simple for you to adapt to your needs.

[Compare Bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031217/what-is-the-fastest-way-i-can-compare-two-equal-size-bitmaps-to-determine-whethe)

Answer (score 0):

Since `Array` supports the `IStructuralEquatable` interface, you can use structural comparison:

```
using System.Collections;

. . .

var areEqual = StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(array1[i], array2[j]);
```