I Made A Script To Search For An Image On The Screen The Problem is It Takes Too Long
public bool FindImageOnScreen(Bitmap searchFor, Bitmap searchIn)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < searchIn.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < searchIn.Width; y++)
        {
            Log($"X: {x}, Y: {y}");
            if (y != searchIn.Height && x != searchIn.Width)
            {
                // First Check
                if (searchIn.GetPixel(x, y) == searchFor.GetPixel(0, 0))
                {
                    if (searchIn.GetPixel(x + (searchFor.Width / 2), y + (searchFor.Height / 2)) == searchFor.GetPixel(searchFor.Width / 2, searchFor.Height / 2))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

            if (y == searchIn.Height && x == searchIn.Width)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

Above is my script to locate an image on the screen but for some reason it takes minutes to do this, how can i speed this up?
It Worked But it Was Too Slow For me As I need it to work in an Instant

Many things are unlcear. For example: Why do both x and y go till searchIn.Width ? Why do you only check and compare 2 pixels in searchFor ? Please explain more about what exactly you are trying to do.

I know there is some Win32-GDI routine (or a bunch of) where you can get the all pixels colors as an 2D-array of long. Using this method is extremely faster. But I forgot which routines these are.
Also you might consider not to compare all pixels but just each tenth or even hundredth and loop in steps of 10 or 100. Depends on the visual nature of your image data whether this is still reliable

if (searchIn.GetPixel(x, y) == searchFor.GetPixel(0, 0)) will only be true for rmonochrome images whose only color equals the color of the reference bitmap's searchFor 1st pixel ...

Here's a fast way to compare 2 bitmaps pixelwise using Win32-GDI unsafe code (see the marked answer of Eric Forbes) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031217/what-is-the-fastest-way-i-can-compare-two-equal-size-bitmaps-to-determine-whethe

@lidqy why would it only work for monochrome images?

If each pixel of Image A must equal the color of Pixel (0,0) of Image B, Image A must be monochrome (if you compare all pixels of Image A).

your bool return value should be initialised with false and should be set to true only when you have your criteria met ( for what is see you are using probabilities)
hence your test:
if (y != searchIn.Height && x != searchIn.Width)

is useless as it is already handled by For conditions+initialised false.
you can use (learn to use) diagnostic tool embedded in visual studio. it can help to find the bottleneck.
you could iterate until a criteria based on the dimension of the image search ( no way to check last column if you know image has not yet started.
What is Log() doing ? if you write in file you have your answer.
Also if you increased y based on Height (and not on width) it could definitely help...
for (int x = 0; x < searchIn.Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < searchIn.Width; y++) // 2nd .Width: joke or typo?
    {

