# How to call memcmp() on two parts of byte[] (with offset)?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, pinvoke, memcmp

I want to compare parts of `byte[]` efficiently - so I understand `memcmp()` should be used.

I know I can using PInvoke to call `memcmp()` - [Comparing two byte arrays in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289/comparing-two-byte-arrays-in-net)

But, I want to compare only parts of the `byte[]` - using offset, and there is no `memcmp()` with offset since it uses pointers.

```
int CompareBuffers(byte[] buffer1, int offset1, byte[] buffer2, int offset2, int count)
{
  // Somehow call memcmp(&buffer1+offset1, &buffer2+offset2, count)
}
```

Should I use C++/CLI to do that?

Should I use PInvoke with IntPtr? How?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think `memcmp` would be more efficient than the C# equivalent?

Comment: What is the .NET equivalent to memcmp()? I don't want to write it myself since it would either be inefficient or buggy.

Comment: read this thread about http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/863856/Re-memcmp-in-Csharp.aspx

Comment: @Isalamon, I don't see where in the thread there is something about an offset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++/CLI will definitely be the cleanest, but this hardly justifies adding C++/CLI to your project if you aren't already using it.

How about [Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.unsafeaddrofpinnedarrayelement(v=VS.100).aspx)(array, offset)?

Answer (score 14):

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
private static extern unsafe int memcmp(byte* b1, byte* b2, int count);

public static unsafe int CompareBuffers(byte[] buffer1, int offset1, byte[] buffer2, int offset2, int count)
{
    fixed (byte* b1 = buffer1, b2 = buffer2)
    {
        return memcmp(b1 + offset1, b2 + offset2, count);
    }
}
```

You might also want to add some parameter validation.

Comment: Need to add CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl. The default is WinApi or stdcall

Comment: `count` is `size_t` as an unsigned integral type

Answer (score 3):

No matter what you do, you should check that the offset/count values are valid for the given byte arrays. After you do that, I don't see how just doing a `for` loop in C# is going to be any slower than P/Invoking a Win32 method.  Seems like there would be a lot of overhead in the P/Invoke that it would not be worthwhile.

Also, there is always unsafe C#.

As with all performance questions, you should do your own performance testing.  But it sounds to me like you are trying to optimize for performance prematurely.

Comment: Optimized `memcmp` uses SIMD instructions to compare 16 bytes per clock cycle (when the buffers are properly aligned) and also provides cache hinting.  One you write in C# won't do that.  For small lengths, the p/invoke overhead is too much.  But larger buffer sizes really win from calling optimized native code.

Answer (score 2):

No need to P/Invoke in C++/CLI.  Use pin_ptr<> to pin the array.  That gets you a byte*, just add the offset.

Comment: I know. So you suggest using C++/CLI to call memcpy() and not PInvoke?

Comment: PInvoke, like so many references I saw but without offset capabilities. Or maybe just some unsafe code?

Comment: I'll let you think about this for a while.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just not sure what will work and be fastest. If they are equivalent, I prefer C#, but I'm not sure how to write it so it would work best.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way

SequenceEqual from System.Linq

```
 byte[] ByteArray1 = null;
 byte[] ByteArray2 = null;

 ByteArray1 = MyFunct1();
 ByteArray2 = MyFunct2();

 if (ByteArray1.SequenceEqual<byte>(ByteArray2))
 {
    MessageBox.Show("Same");
 }
 else
 {
   MessageBox.Show("Not Equal");
 }
```

Comment: This solution is very slow.

Comment: See this answer for a way more performant approach which works on .NET 6+: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48599119/227779