# String Comparison vs Array Comparison in .NET

Tags: .net, arrays, performance, string, comparison

I've got a speed critical piece of code which involves the comparison of 2 4 byte arrays. I've been trying to work out the fastest way to achieve this, and have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289/comparing-two-byte-arrays-in-net).

Doing 100,000,000 comparisons using pinvoke and memcmp takes ~9.5 seconds, using the UnsafeCompare method posted in the above link takes ~3.5 seconds.

If set 2 4 character strings and compare those using s1 == s2 it takes ~0.5 seconds. If I use string.Compare(s1, s2) it takes about ~12 seconds.

Is there some way I can get my byte array comparisons to compare is speed to doing s1 == s2? And if not, could there be any problems with me doing something like below, basically storing my byte arrays as strings?

```
        string s1 = Convert.ToChar(1).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(2).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(3).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(4).ToString();
        string s2 = Convert.ToChar(1).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(2).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(3).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(4).ToString();

        if (s1 == s2)
            .....
```

Hoping someone can help me out with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend these steps:

1. Compare the two 4-byte arrays byte-by-byte, i.e. `a[0] == b[1] && … && a[3] == b[3]`. This will be *much faster* than any calls to `memcmp` and alikes. Most likely, the JIT compiler will compile this into an efficient (and inline) sequence of instructions. You are comparing *only four bytes*, you cannot expect an algorithm designed for comparing arbitrarily long memory chunks to perform better.
2. Think about storing the data as 32-bit integers instead of 4-byte arrays. That will provide another performance gain, because the comparison (`a == b`) will be translated into a single 32-bit comparison instruction.
3. **Try to rethink your algorithm** — is it really necessary to perform 100 million comparisons? Aren't there any options to reduce the time complexity of the algorithm? *That* would yield a considerable performance boost.

However, without knowing a broader context it's hard to recommend any better and specific optimizations.

Comment: I tried what you suggested in 1. This took about ~8s. 2 I think is a good option, the int32 comparison takes ~0.33s, so that's the fastest of the bunch. The 100m comparisons was just for the test, the actual app wont be hitting it quite so hard.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried out this for speed, but what about hard-coding the length and doing a comparison like this:

```
byte[] one = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
byte[] two = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 4 };

bool isEqual = ((one[0] == two[0]) && (one[1] == two[1]) && (one[2] == two[2]) && (one[3] == two[3]));
```

Comment: As mentioned above, this seems to be slower than the string comparison also.