# How to compare two arrays of bytes

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two byte arrays with the exact same content. I tried:

```
if (bytearray1 == bytearray2) {...} else {...}
```

and

```
if (Array.Equals(bytearray1, bytearray2)) {....} else {...}
```

All time it goes to the else! I don't know why! I checked both arrays manually several times!!!

Comment: See Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289/comparing-two-byte-arrays-in-net

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try using the [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) extension method. For example:

```
byte[] a1 = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
byte[] a2 = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
bool areEqual = a1.SequenceEqual(a2); // true
```

Answer (score 12):

The `==` operator compares by reference; those are two different instances.

`Array.Equals` is really `Object.Equals`, which calls the instances `Equals` method.
Since arrays do not override `Equals()`, this too compares by reference.

Instead, you should call the LINQ `SequenceEqual()` method.

Answer (score 8):

Both the `==` operator and the Equals method will test reference equality. Since you have two separate arrays, they will never be equal.

Since you want to test that both arrays have the same content in the same order, try using the [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) method instead.

Answer (score -5):

As an alternative, if you are not comfortable using [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) you can use the System.Convert class...

```
byte[] a1;
byte[] a2;

if (System.Convert.ToBase64String(a1) == System.Convert.ToBase64String(a2)) {
    doSomething();
}
else {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: I would be "not confortable" converting two arrays to string and then iterating on the string again to make a comparison. I would prefer iterating just once using the LINQ method or making my own method.

Comment: Terribly and needlessly inefficient. Like Davi Fiamenghi said, either use SequenceEqual or just do simple loop comparison.

Comment: It would depend on the whether one side of the comparison is already in base64 though, in which case you may as well convert the other side. This scenario is reasonably common when you want to present human readable byte[] arrays. For example, when using hashes for document verification