# Is there a memcmp equivalent for comparing byte arrays in Mono?

Tags: c#, c, mono, arrays, memcmp

There is a well-known efficiency for comparing two byte-arrays in .Net by importing the `memcmp` function from `msvcrt.dll`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445405).

Is there an equivalent library import in mono?  Would it need to be different when running mono on linux or on windows?  Or is there another fast byte array comparison technique that works well in mono?  I'm looking for something better than just iterating over the arrays in c#.

**Update**

Based on Matt Patenaude's comment, I think this might work well:

```
#if __MonoCS__
    [DllImport("c", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
#else
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
#endif
    public static extern int memcmp(byte[] b1, byte[] b2, UIntPtr count);
```

But I have not yet tried it.  I've never done p/invoke on mono before.  I'm using the signature recommended on [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/msvcrt.memcmp).  Is this going to be compatible?

Looking for a Mono-focused answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know much about Mono or .NET, but `memcmp` is a standard ISO C function, so most (all) UNIXes should support it already. When not on Windows, there might be a way in Mono to access the native libc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your update, you shouldn't be using the `__MonoCS__` preprocessor. It means you would have to recompile the library for Mono and .NET. The better way is to use `dllmap` functionality in Mono and only use the `msvcrt.dll` DllImport.

Instead define a "AssemblyName.dll.config" and use the `dllmap` tag to map `msvcrt.dll` to `c` when run on Mono.

Example:

```
<configuration>
    <dllmap dll="msvcrt.dll" target="libc.so.6" />
</configuration>
```

More detail on dllmap here: http://www.mono-project.com/Config_DllMap

**EDIT**

And if for some reason `c` doesn't work, `libc.so` should work.

Comment: Amen to "do not compile a separate version for Mono".

Comment: Ok, but is the memcmp signature still valid for mono?

Comment: Yeah, it should be. I'm not too sure about your `c` target though. Give me a minute to boot into my linux partition and try it out...

Comment: Just tried it out. `c` doesn't work. For some reason, `libc.so` isn't executable, had to set the target to `libc.so.6`. Updated the answer with that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unsafe` code blocks to access byte arrays almost as fast as native `memcmp`. Before you go down that road, make sure a straight `for` loop isn't fast enough for your purposes.

Comment: Now that I have a working answer, I will benchmark and see which makes more sense for my purposes.  Thanks for the suggestion.