# Checking equality for two byte arrays

Tags: c#

I am checking the equality of two byte arrays, and I wanted some help because what I have returns false even though the arrays should be equal.

Within my debug I could see both of a1 and b1 are equal, but it is not going inside the while loop to increment i.

```
public bool Equality(byte[] a1, byte[] b1)
{
    int i;
    bool bEqual;
    if (a1.Length == b1.Length)
    {
        i = 0;
        while ((i < a1.Length) && (a1[i]==b1[i]))
        {
            i++;
        }

        if (i == a1.Length)
        {
            bEqual = true;
        }
    }
    return bEqual;
}
```

This always returns false: `(a1[i]==b1[i])`.

Comment: Where is your return statement?

Comment: Is hashB supposed to be b1?

Comment: as far as i can tell it doesn't return anything

Comment: Which framework version?

Comment: This code does not compile (On .NET 4) as `bEqual` was not initialized. If I initialize this variable to `false` then I don't see any problem with this code (Eventhough for equality check you can actually break out the while loop as soon as any of the element is not equal)

Comment: You cannot keep changing the question this much after we answer it, all the responses are going to be confused between different versions of the question. Post it as a new question...

Comment: I have rolled back the question. If you need to make that drastic of a change please open a new question.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to add a return value somewhere. This should work:

```
public bool Equality(byte[] a1, byte[] b1)
{
   int i;
   if (a1.Length == b1.Length)
   {
      i = 0;
      while (i < a1.Length && (a1[i]==b1[i])) //Earlier it was a1[i]!=b1[i]
      {
          i++;
      }
      if (i == a1.Length)
      {
          return true;
      }
   }

   return false;
}
```

But this is much simpler:

```
return a1.SequenceEqual(b1);
```

Alternatively, you could use [`IStructuralEquatable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.istructuralequatable(v=vs.110).aspx) from .NET 4:

```
return ((IStructuralEquatable)a1).Equals(b1, StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer)
```

---

If performance is a concern, I'd recommend rewriting your code to use the [`Binary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.binary) class, which is specifically optimized for this kind of use case:

```
public bool Equality(Binary a1, Binary b1)
{
    return a1.Equals(b1);
}
```

A quick benchmark on my machine gives the following stats:

```
Method                   Min         Max         Avg
binary equal:          0.868       3.076       0.933    (best)
for loop:              2.636      10.004       3.065
sequence equal:        8.940      30.124      10.258
structure equal:     155.644     381.052     170.693
```

Download [this LINQPad file](http://share.linqpad.net/gar8ne.linq) to run the benchmark yourself.

Comment: i am using this to compare two different files and return the difference ( what records were added or removed) not that it runs and loops properly i am not getting a returned message about the difference of the files in which one file had records removed

Comment: @Masriyah So what you really want to do is implement a diff algorithm? That's an entirely different task than simply checking equality. I recommend you look at Google's [diff-match-patch](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) library.

Comment: I went ahead and uploaded the other parts of my code which is relating to this. Maybe you can take a look and point something out. i've been running around in circles with this all day. thanks

Comment: Logically there is no difference between OP's code and this code as far as first solution is concerned. OP only forgot to initialize `bEqual` to false which if done would also yield the same result.

Comment: i posted a new question if you can take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473580/returning-records-that-have-been-added-or-removed-after-two-file-comparison

Comment: StructuralComparisons has slower performance than the for loop

Comment: @alhpe Yes. I've updated my answer with notes on performance.

Comment: It's a pity the Binary class doesn't exist in .net core :(

Comment: You can also look into using `Span<T>` - according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48599119/533837) it's very performant.

Answer (score 44):

To check equality you can just write:

```
var areEqual =  a1.SequenceEqual(b1);
```

Comment: That technically requires LINQ which might not match his framework

Comment: But if it does match his framework it is a much better way of doing it.

Comment: @Moop Linq has been around for 6 years now, surely most people have upgraded to at least framework 3.5 by now.

Comment: @MikePrecup in this day an age, ***unless explicitly specified***, I think it is safe to assume that any project being worked on is 3.5+. [67% of all .NET users are on version 4 and 26% are on some version of 3](http://web.archive.org/web/20120919192827/http://statowl.com/microsoft_dotnet.php).

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend some short-circuiting to make things a bit simpler, and use of `object.ReferenceEquals` to short-circuit for cases when the arrays are the same reference (`a1 = b1`):

```
public bool Equality(byte[] a1, byte[] b1)
{
    // If not same length, done
    if (a1.Length != b1.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // If they are the same object, done
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(a1,b1))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Loop all values and compare
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (a1[i] != b1[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // If we got here, equal
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public bool Equality(byte[] a1, byte[] b1)
{
   if(a1 == null || b1 == null)
       return false;
   int length = a1.Length;
   if(b1.Length != length)
      return false;
   while(length >0) {
       length--;
       if(a1[length] != b1[length])
          return false;           
   }
   return true;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add some return statements:

```
public bool Equality(byte[] a1, byte[] b1)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (a1.Length == b1.Length)
    {
        while ((i < a1.Length) && (a1[i]==b1[i]))
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return i == a1.Length;
}
```

Or, better yet

```
public bool Equality(byte[] a1, byte[] b1)
{
    if(a1.Length != b1.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (a1[i] != b1[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You second answer might throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception

Comment: Do the length check first, it is less expensive.

Comment: The first won't work because if `a1.Length == 0` and `b1.Length > 0`