# Returning records that have been added or removed after two file comparison

Tags: c#, winforms

I am comparing two files and one of the files might have added or removed items. I am checking to see if there are differences between the two files and if so then what are those differences whether records have been added or removed. I would like to return those records (added or removed)

With what i have it tells me whether the file had items removed or added but it is not **returning the the items that have been added or removed**. Any help to what i am missing would be appreciated.

```
   foreach (ExcelRow rowA in fileA.excelRows)
    {
        if (!fileB.ContainsHash(rowA.rowHash))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Files are NOT the same. Data was REMOVED.\n" + rowA.ToString());
        }

    }

    foreach (ExcelRow rowB in fileB.excelRows)
    {
         if (!fileA.ContainsHash(rowB.rowHash))
         {
              MessageBox.Show("Row added" + rowB.ToString());
         }
    }

public List<ExcelRow> excelRows = new List<ExcelRow>();

        public bool ContainsHash(byte[] hashToLook)
        {
            bool found;
            found = false;
            foreach (ExcelRow eRow in excelRows)
            {
                found = EqualHash(eRow.rowHash, hashToLook);

                if (found)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return found;
        }

        public static bool EqualHash(byte[] hashA, byte[] hashB)
        {
            bool bEqual ;
            int i ;

            bEqual  = false;
            if (hashA.Length == hashB.Length)
            {

                i = 0;
                while ((i < hashA.Length) && (hashA[i] == hashB[i]))
                {
                    i++ ;
                }
                if (i == hashA.Length)
                {
                    bEqual = true;
                }
            }
            return bEqual ;
        }
```

**Reading Files:**

```
public ExcelInfo ReadExcel(OpenFileDialog openFileDialog)
        {
            var _excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(openFileDialog.FileName);
            var _info = from c in _excelFile.WorksheetNoHeader() select c;

            ExcelRow excelRow;
            ExcelInfo resp;

            resp = new ExcelInfo();

            foreach (var item in _info)
            {
                excelRow = new ExcelRow();
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(0));
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(1));
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(2));
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(3));
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(4));
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(5));
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(6));
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(7));
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(8));
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(9));
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(10));
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(11));
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(12));

                excelRow.CalculateHash();
                resp.excelRows.Add(excelRow);
            }
            return resp;
        }
```

**Calculate Hash:**

```
public void CalculateHash()
        {
            byte[] rowBytes;
            byte[] cellBytes;
            int pos;
            int numRowBytes;

            numRowBytes = 0;
            foreach (string cellText in lstCells)
            {
                numRowBytes += NumBytes(cellText);
            }

            //Allocate space to calculate the HASH of a single row

            rowBytes = new byte[numRowBytes];
            pos = 0;

            //Concatenate the cellText of each row into a single byte array
            foreach (string cellText in lstCells)
            {
                cellBytes = GetBytes(cellText);
                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(cellBytes, 0, rowBytes, pos, cellBytes.Length);
                pos = cellBytes.Length;
            }
            rowHash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(rowBytes);
        }
```

WHILE DEBUGGING:

```
if (!fileB.ContainsHash(rowA.rowHash))
```

fileB contains three rows and fileA contains 4 rows.

fileB = 3, 
rowA = the first row in fileA and (.rowHash) is byte[16]

as i continue to ContainHash method, byte[] hashToLook = 16 - shouldn't this be rowA?

excelRows = 3 (fileB)

then 
EqualHash(eRow.rowHash, hashToLook) is (first row in fileA, byte[16])

am i passing in rowA wrong?

Comment: Please show how you are calculating the hash. I.e. the implementation of `ExcelRow.CalculateHash`.

Comment: @Alex i added the method above. Thanks

Comment: I think I have spotted the error in the hash calculation. You need to replace `pos = cellBytes.Length;` with `pos += cellBytes.Length;`

Comment: Also, hash collisions may occasionally occur. So if the hash matches, you really should also compare each of the fields to ensure that two rows are equal. Although with the MD5 over all the bytes, chances of that occurring are very low.

Comment: @Alex I think i am very close - now it is showing that the line before the line i removed is the one removed. ex: file has 1, 2,3,4 (i removed 5) it returns stating that 4 was removed

Comment: I don't see anything that could cause that. Did you change anything else, or is the code listed now the same as what you are testing with?

Comment: @Alex the only thing i have added that is not here is an if statement to check if the files are the same and no changes have been made and that is skipped with my current testing because the files i am using are different

Comment: well then I am afraid I have to give up. I don't see any errors that could cause what you are describing.

Comment: @Alex last try...please - i posted a process when debugging and i feel like i am not passing in rowA properly from the start to ContainsHash method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just add two lists to keep track of items that are in A but not in B and items that are in B but not in A:

```
var notInA = new List<ExcelRow>();
var notInB = new List<ExcelRow>();
```

Now in your code, add them to the appropriate list:

```
foreach (ExcelRow rowA in fileA.excelRows)
{
    if (!fileB.ContainsHash(rowA.rowHash))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Files are NOT the same. Data was REMOVED.\n" + rowA.ToString());
        notInB.Add(rowA);
    }

}

foreach (ExcelRow rowB in fileB.excelRows)
{
     if (!fileA.ContainsHash(rowB.rowHash))
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Row added" + rowB.ToString());
          notInA.Add(rowB);
     }
}
```

Comment: To get complete answer some sort of `DiffResult` type is needed... and method declaration (which is likely main problem for OP).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If we are considering this from the perspective of file "A" being the original (i.e earlier version) then "notInB" is semantically equal to "Removed" and "notInA" is semantically equal to "Added".

Comment: I just tried this and first it shows that three items were removed and two items are added. even though between the two files i just removed one row

Comment: @Masriyah you removed a single row from "file B"?

Comment: yes - i altered if and else statments and now it still says that 3 rows were removed not just 1

Comment: @Masriyah what things are included in the calculation of the "rowHash"? Is it possible that the row position is a part of the hash calculation?

Comment: @Masriyah Check my answer. Clearly there is a silly bug in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `hashA[i] != hashB[i]` to `hashA[i] == hashB[i]` :)

Comment: Yes i made this change yet i am still getting what i have mentioned above.