# C# : Check if two objects have same data

Tags: c#, .net

Assuming that `Obj1` and `Obj2` are objects of the same class and the class contains only fields, is it possible to check whether the two objects have the same data if the fields of the class are not known?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible without knowing the names of the fields. I may be wrong though

Comment: It is possible. Writing answer now (clue, it involves reflection).

Comment: http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/

Comment: Yes, using lots and lots of reflection

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two objects by iterating recursively through all the properties' properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062428/comparing-two-objects-by-iterating-recursively-through-all-the-properties-prope)

Comment: Using Reflection or BinaryFormatter to compare serialized raw byte[] arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare the content of two objects for equality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375996/compare-the-content-of-two-objects-for-equality)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var haveSameData = false;

foreach(PropertyInfo prop in Obj1.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    haveSameData = prop.GetValue(Obj1, null).Equals(prop.GetValue(Obj2, null));

    if(!haveSameData)
       break;
}
```

This is based on assumptions (objects are of the same type), and could probably be refactored so that it's more defensive,
 but I'm keeping it readable so you can grasp what I'm trying to do.

In a nutshell, use reflection to iterate over the fields and check the values of each until satisfied that they don't match (no need to keep iterating after this).

Comment: An exercise for "Coding man" may be to handle complex property types such as generic lists.

Comment: @RobEpstein: yes, I will try some time :)

Comment: question said class only contains fields and not properties. Confused why your answer got accepted

Answer (score -4):

Try this assert:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(Obj1, Obj2);
```

Comment: This would be good but it compares objects that implement `ICollection` only.

Comment: This will use the built in .net Equal methods which will do a referential equality check.