# Validate Stored Encrypted Password in SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012, sha256

In SQL Server I run a command:

```
Select HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', '12345678') as EncryptedString
```

It gives `0xEF797C8118F02DFB649607DD5D3F8C7623048C9C063D532CC95C5ED7A898A64F` this string as an output, this string has 66 characters.

On the same side, Itried to encrypt password from C# code, using this:

```
public string GetSHAEncryptedCode(string Text)
{
    //SHA1 sha26 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    SHA256 sha26 = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] sha256Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Text);
    byte[] cryString = sha26.ComputeHash(sha256Bytes);
    string sha256Str = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < cryString.Length; i++)
    {
        sha256Str += cryString[i].ToString("X");
    }
    return sha256Str;
}
```

Suupose, if I enter same "12345678" in C# code it returns me a string of 62 character long, string is `EF797C8118F02DFB64967DD5D3F8C762348C9C63D532CC95C5ED7A898A64F`. Now how could i validate the encrypted string coming from sql server and the other string from C# code in order to login the user from login page?

Comment: Other than the obvious `0x` on the front, could you highlight the differences between the strings? My internal diff algorithm is struggling.

Comment: compare them? They are the same.

Comment: I'd check the `cryString[i].ToString("X");` line - the result string missing `0` char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C# format string is incorrect - it it missing leading `0`s when the hex value is less than `10`.

Instead you need to use `"X2"` as the format string so that it is padded to 2 numbers:

```
public string GetSHAEncryptedCode(string Text)
{
    //SHA1 sha26 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    SHA256 sha26 = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] sha256Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Text);
    byte[] cryString = sha26.ComputeHash(sha256Bytes);
    string sha256Str = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < cryString.Length; i++)
    {
        sha256Str += cryString[i].ToString("X2");
    }
    return sha256Str;
}
```

This correctly returns `EF797C8118F02DFB649607DD5D3F8C7623048C9C063D532CC95C5ED7A898A64F` and then you can just append `0x` to the start.

In any case, you should not really be converting the values to a string anyway. `HASHBYTES()` and `sha256.ComputeHash()` both return byte arrays, so it is more efficient and safer to just compare those instead. You can use the methods described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289/comparing-two-byte-arrays-in-net) to do that.

Or maybe better still, I assume you are storing the password in the database as encrypted (aren't you...?), so just encrypt the input value to a byte array in C#, then pass that to the database and use something like

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @username AND password = @passwordBytes`