# SSE instructions defying RAM theoretical bandwidth

Tags: c#, performance, mono, performance-testing, simd

[I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294580/sse-instruction-to-check-if-byte-array-is-zeroes-c-sharp) a method checking a byte[] for being all zeroes. Mono.Simd offers so high performance that I am wondering if this is even possible.

```
static unsafe bool IsAllZeros(byte[] data)
{
    fixed (byte* bytes = data) {
        int len = data.Length;
        int rem = len % (16*16);
        Vector16b* b = (Vector16b*)bytes;
        Vector16b* e = b + len / (16*16);
        Vector16b zero = Vector16b.Zero;

        while (b < e) {
            if ((*(b)|*(b+1)|*(b+2)|*(b+3)|*(b+4)|*(b+5)|*(b+6)|*(b+7)|*(b+8)|
             *(b+9)|*(b+10)|*(b+11)|*(b+12)|*(b+13)|*(b+14)|*(b+15)) != zero)
                return false;
            b += 16;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rem; i++)
            if (data [len - 1 - i] != 0)
                return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Code above processes 256 MB in 2,6477 ms giving 94 GB/s. **Is this even possible?**

My DDR2 memory has 800 Mhz frequency. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_bandwidth#Bandwidth_computation_and_nomenclature) gives a formula for a theoretical maximum bandwidth as 800M*2*64*2 = 25 GB/s.

Comment: You are only processing 1/16 of the array.

Comment: Also is `b += 16` correct ? Shouldn't it be `b++` ?

Comment: Loop processes 16 vectors in one iteration, that is why it moves 16. By the way, you should have posted it on code review page instead. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108470/sse-instruction-to-check-if-byte-array-is-zeroes-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good that you did the bandwidth calculation, because it exposed a major bug in your algorithm -- the loop ends when it reaches `e`, which is only 1/16th of the way through the input.

The actual maximum theoretical bandwidth in your system is just a bit less than 12.8 GB/s (DDR2/6400 rating, times two channels, minus a few cycles that the DRAM is busy doing refresh and can't be accessed).  This differs from the calculation in your question because you used a factor of two for DDR, and applied it to a number that already included that factor.

The bandwidth of your algorithm is 16MB per 2.65 ms or 6.0 GB/s (assuming that no non-zero elements were found, so the entire array needed to be scanned), about half the theoretical limit.  Not bad at all for untuned C#, even with the Mono-SIMD weaver.

Comment: SIMD code was eventually beaten. Current record is 256MB per 26 ms or 9.8 GB/s of bandwidth.