# Comparing 2 hashed byte arrays

Tags: c#, hash, md5

Consider the following code:

```
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] hashedBytes;
    byte[] previousHashedBytes;

    UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
    // New hashedBytes array
    hashedBytes = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(someString + theValue));
    // previousHashedBytes retrieved from DB
    previousHashedBytes = GetPreviousValueFromDB();
```

The application then inserts hashedBytes into a database.  I need to make sure *due to a new policy* that hashedBytes value cannot be reused, so I need some way to compare an existing hashedBytes value with a new one.

**Note**:  the value for `someString` is always the same.

How does one compare `previousHashedBytes` with `hashedBytes` to see if they are the same?

Comment: Look into [`Enumerable.SequenceEquals()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.7#System_Linq_Enumerable_SequenceEqual__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if you only have the byte hash in DB, you want to compare two byte array ?

You can get this here: [Comparing two byte arrays in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8808245/3937941)

One of the options that might work for you is:

```
StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(hashedBytes,
 previousHashedBytes)
```